# Kohler kitchen faucet - replaced side sprayer now faucet doesn't work

Tags: kitchens, faucet

I have an older Kohler kitchen faucet with a separate valve and side sprayer (3 hole).  The sprayer hose is going bad.  In making sure that I purchased the correct thing I removed the side sprayer at both ends.  The part that attaches to the sink uses the Kohler quick disconnect (that I cussed at until I figured it out).  If I turn the faucet on the sprayer still works fine.  But the main faucet now will not - it leaks out of the sprayer quick disconnect part.

I read about a diverter value but, to this point I haven't disassembled the valve part.

The whole thing assembled:

[image: The whole thing assembled]

The quick disconnect side:
[image]

Any thoughts?  The faucet is a good 15 years old.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - did you reattach the sprayer and it is leaking at the quick disconnect, or is the disconnect still disconnected? It may be that the sprayer hose is always pressurized when the faucet is on, so a leak at the disconnect may reduce the water pressure to the faucet itself.

Comment: Also, check the Kohler website for manuals and troubleshooting if you haven't already.

Comment: Are you saying the sprayer is supposed to work even when the faucet taps are closed? Is that what you mean by "separate valve"?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion.  I reattached the sprayer and now the main faucet doesn't work.  I cleaned the faucet filter just in case it got some goop in it.  When everything is connected only the sprayer works.  Letting go of the sprayer trigger is supposed to divert to the main faucet but nothing comes out and after a very brief time (~2 secs) the connection between the assembly and the sprayer begins to leak.

Comment: I see 5 hoses going into the faucet undeneath, from your picture.  3  plastic composite hoses (braided white) and 2 copper. just which of thoses go directly to your side sprayer is not obvious. And the other 4 hoses, is hard telling what is up with that.  There should only be 3 hoses. two feeds the fauct ( 1 hot and 1 cold) and one coming out of the faucet to your side sprayer. If you can label all the 5 hoses, it will help seeing what is going on. Perhaps 2 of the hoses feeds the pivoting neck of the main faucet...?

Comment: I think @Meta_Alchemy may be on to something there. How about a picture of the faucet itself. Is it on a pull-out hose of any sort? Also, did you turn off the water to the entire faucet before starting on this? Maybe in turning the valves on the supply lines, some crud was dislodged inside the pipes that has now lodged itself in the faucet's side of the supply so water can't get past it. (Yes, that would be a large bit of crud...)